# Зачем создавать интерфейс IClone при копировании объектов в C#

Tags: c#

Скажите, я попробовал реализацию последнего кода без интерфейса IClone. И у меня все получилось. Код так же само работает. Тогда зачем создавать этот интерфейс????
Если есть причины его вставлять в код, тогда можно будет например заменить этот интерфейс на абстрактный класс. Разницы ведь не будет, мы также укажем там метод, который потом полиморфным методом реализуем в классах наследниках???
Пожалуйста, дайте расширенный ответ.

```
var tom = new Person("Tom", 23, new Company("Microsoft"));
var bob = (Person)tom.Clone();
bob.Work.Name = "Google";
Console.WriteLine(tom.Work.Name);

class Person : ICloneable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Company Work { get; set; }
    public Person(string name, int age, Company company)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Work = company;
    }
    public object Clone() => new Person(Name, Age, new Company(Work.Name));
}
class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company(string name) => Name = name;
}
```

Comment: Это из разряда "Зачем нужны интерфейсы". Ну хорошо, простейшая задача: Узнать, поддерживает объект клонирование, или нет, в случае если нет, то скопировать вручную все свойства в новый объект, если да - вызвать метод клонирования. Как поступите? С интерфейсом можете сделать так `if (tom is ICloneable item) { var newItem = item.Clone(); }`. Или другая задача, есть массив интерфейсов `List<IUser>`, который заполнен десятками различных классов, с различными типами, вам надо у каждого типа вызвать `Clone()`, как поступите?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ справедливости ради, за 10 лет мне ни разу не попалась задача, требующая ICloneable, так что вопрос не такой глупый...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я и не говорил, что он глупый, он очень похож на типичный вопрос "Зачем нужны интерфейсы", и наверно дубликатом было бы правильно его закрыть. А так, зависит от задач, от проекта. Я допустим за всю свою "программерскую" жизнь, еще ни разу не использовал клонирование, вот просто не требовалось. Так что, тут главное знать зачем и как, а там уже принимать по необходимости)